# LINQ to Entities - multiple OrderBy methods do not work

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities, sql-order-by

If I apply two `OrderBy` methods to my query, like that

```
query.OrderBy(rec => rec.Name).OrderByDescending(rec => rec.Title);
```

Then only second method is applied, the first one is ignored. Is it a bug? What if I need to have ascending ordering for one column and descending ordering for another? Is it not achievable at all by method syntax?

Answer (score 25):

Try this:

```
query.OrderBy(rec => rec.Name).ThenByDescending(rec => rec.Title);
```

Your second OrderBy is reseting your first result set.  That's why the `ThenBy` extension exists.  It will preserve your first result set, while applying additional sorting to it.

Essentially, your existing solution as psuedo SQL would look something like this:

```
results = SELECT * FROM Obj ORDER BY Name;
results = SELECT * FROM results ORDER BY Title DESC;
```

...which isn't what you want.  The `ThenBy` extension would look something like this:

```
results = SELECT * FROM Obj ORDER BY Name ASC, Title DESC
```